# Configuring 2 XBee Modules on OSX for wireless connection

Tags: macos, xbee

I am trying find out how and with which program for OSX (10.5.8) I can configure serial ports? I am trying to establish a wireless connection between two Xbee´s (RF modules) and cannot figure out how to use ZTerm nor screen under Terminal. The setup I am using is: an Arduino+Xbeeshield+Xbee with external power supply, and an xbee on the xbee explorer connected to the Computer via USB. 
 I am trying to gather information on this through various forums, but most of them cover the configuration issue for PC using X-CTU (which I tried with CrossOver but it doesn´t recognize ny of my ports). According to one source, using screen under Terminal should show me all my serial ports, particularly /dev/tty.KeySerial1  - but it doesn´t show, even though I´ve plugged in both my arduino+xbee shield and the xbee on the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/tty.KeySerial1 is incorrect.

First step is to get the FTDI USB driver installed if it has not yet been installed. The fastest way to determine if it is installed or not is to connect the XBee Explorer board. Then go look in /dev for a device named tty.usbserial-XXXXXXXX (Xs will be a unique hex ID). If you see multiple devices like this, then you probably have the Arduino plugged in too and you will need to disconnect it to determine what the device name is for the XBee Explorer board.

Once you know the device name, all you need to do is the command "screen /dev/tty.usbserial-XXXXXXXXX 9600". That should do it for you.

Comment: I usually get a list of all the usbserial devices both before and after plugging in the XBee, and then compare the two to find the new tty associated with the XBee.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the tty device itself using stty.  Be sure to redirect *input* from the terminal you want to configure, as stty operates on it's input.  For instance, to set a serial port to 9600, no parity, 8 data bits, and 1 stop bit, aka "9600N81" in Windows parlance, try:

```
stty 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb < /dev/tty.usbserial-xxxxxxxx
```

Programmatically, you do this by opening the serial port and using the termios(4) ioctls on the device.  See the termios(4) man page for more assistance.